# Android slidable listview with googlemaps

Tags: android, google-maps, listview, sliding

I was wondering if there is any library for android that helps displaying listview and google map in the same screen, similar to the Transit app.

So, when u drag the blue listview header up, as in the picture, the list moves on top of the map, whereas the map shrinks but maintains the focus of the location dot in the center.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check this [Android Sliding Up Panel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) library which provides a simple way to add a draggable sliding up panel (popularized by Google Music and Google Maps) to your Android application.

Simply add the following dependency to your `build.gradle` file to use the latest version:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.1'
}
```

Here's a [sample](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=915)  map animation (sliding panel) with ListView.